# Defining an alias to pgfplot table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have one file that plots a tikzpicture. I want to be able to use pgfplot tables (`\loadedtableI` or `\loadedtableII` in the MWE below) to plot the same figure twice. How can I define an alias to a table, without reloading it?

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data1.txt}
 X    Y
 1    1
 2    2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data2.txt}
 X    Y
 1    1
 2    1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot table {\loadedtable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{document}

  \pgfplotstableread{data1.txt}\loadedtableI
  \pgfplotstableread{data2.txt}\loadedtableII

  % \def\loadtable{\loadedtableI} Something like this
  \input{myfig}
  % \def\loadtable{\loadedtableII}
  \input{myfig}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some expansion.  The following seems to work in this case

```
\edef\Temp{\unexpanded{\addplot} table {\expandonce\CurrentTable}}\Temp
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data1.txt}
 X    Y
 1    1
 2    2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data2.txt}
 X    Y
 1    1
 2    1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{myfig.tex}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \edef\Temp{\unexpanded{\addplot} table {\expandonce\CurrentTable}}\Temp;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{document}

  \pgfplotstableread{data1.txt}\loadedtableI
  \pgfplotstableread{data2.txt}\loadedtableII

  \def\CurrentTable{\loadedtableI}
  \input{myfig}
  \def\CurrentTable{\loadedtableII}
  \input{myfig}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that I am _not_ in anyway an expert on expansion (just in case any of the regulars here think that I finally get expansion).  So if someone who is has a better solution, feel free to post an answer and I am happy to delete this one,